# Assigning and comparing chars to ints

Tags: c, arrays, char, int

I have a char array:

```
char arr[5];
```

Say I assign it the values:

```
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
arr[2] = 3;
arr[3] = 4;
arr[4] = 5;
```

When I print using:

```
printf("%c\n", arr[0])
```

nothing is printed out (only the newline).

When I print using:

```
printf("%d\n", arr[0])
```

the value 1 is printed out (and the newline).

Why is this happening? What exactly is going on when you assign a char variable an integer? Is it casted?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: It's likely printing ASCII Character SOH which has no visible equivalent

Comment: You're printing control-A through control-E.  You can see that by running the output through `od -c` or `sed l` or something similar that makes invisible characters visible.

Answer (score 1):

The number `1` has a different ASCII value to the character `'1'`, which is 49.
When you use `%c` it treats this as an ASCII character.

If you initialised your array with characters instead of numbers then you will see what you expect from

```
printf("%c\n", arr[0])
```

i.e.

```
arr[0] = '1';
arr[1] = '2';
arr[2] = '3';
arr[3] = '4';
arr[4] = '5';
```

Answer (score 0):

The character codes 1-5 are non-printable control characters, <kbd>Control-A</kbd> to <kbd>Control-E</kbd>.

The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char arr[5];

    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = 2;
    arr[2] = 3;
    arr[3] = 4;
    arr[4] = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%c\n", arr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

can be compiled into a program `ccc`, and then run:

```
$ ccc




$ ccc | odx
0x0000: 01 0A 02 0A 03 0A 04 0A 05 0A                     ..........
0x000A:
$ ccc | od -c | so
0000000  001  \n 002  \n 003  \n 004  \n 005  \n                        
0000012
$ ccc | sed l
\001$

\002$

\003$

\004$

\005$

$
```

Although there are no visible characters for the values 1-5 (the control characters have no visible representation on the terminal), the hex dump program (`odx`, a home-brew program), `od -c` and `sed l` all see the control characters in the output.

If you want to see the digits `'1'` to `'5'`, use the single-quoted character constants in place of the (unquoted) numbers.

Incidentally, in the calls:

```
printf("%c\n", arr[0]);
printf("%d\n", arr[0]);
```

`arr[0]` is promoted to `int` automatically by the standard rules for calling variadic (variable argument list) functions such as `printf()`.  All the arguments of type `char` (including signed and unsigned variants) and `short` in the variable part of the argument list are automatically promoted to `int`, and any values of type `float` are promoted to `double`.  (Conceivably, `unsigned short` could be promoted to `unsigned int` if plain `int` can't store the maximum `unsigned short` value, but that would mean that `sizeof(short) == sizeof(int)` so the promotion is a no-op anyway. Now I've covered my butt, you can forget about it.)  The conversion specification in the format string controls how the `int` value will be presented to the user.